# Configuration of unixODBC after compiling from source

Tags: compiling, make

I am using a device that is running Yoco Linux on a 32 Bit architecture. It does not provide a package manager or a compiler thus not allowing me to compile on it. Instead I use a Ubuntu Virtual Machine where I compile what I need, copy it to the device and install there.

That what I did for example for Python3.4 - it was as easy as:

```
./configure
make
```

On the Ubuntu Virtual Machine and

```
make install
```

on the device running Yocto.

But now I am facing a minor problem with `unixODBC`. `./configure` and `make` are completed without any problems. What I did not know is that I also need a `gcc` compiler for `make install` and therefore not making it possible to use it on the device. Naivly I thought I could just copy the libraries completly compiled on Ubuntu to the deivce but this didn't work. All configuration is not done.

My question is: is there an argument for `make` or any kind of other option to build all I need on Ubuntu, copy it to the device and start the configuration routine that is build into unixODBCs installation?

I took a look around through the `Makefile` hoping to find a clue but without luck. It also is hard to grasp what kind of configuration is done after compilation was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing programs from the source you can often use the `DESTDIR` flag to achieve this.

1. Create a new directory: `mkdir /tmp/uodbcinst`
2. Install: `make DESTDIR=/tmp/uodbcinst/ install`
3. Archive the result `tar -cpzf ~/uodbcinst.tar.gz -C /tmp/uodbcinst .`
4. Extract the result on the other system `tar -C / -xf uodbcinst.tar.gz`

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested these commands, please double check the syntax. Extracting a tarball into the root directory is very dangerous.*

You may also want to consider adjusting the `--sysconfdir` option when running `./configure` so that the resulting program looks in the `/etc/` folder for configuration files instead of `/usr/local/etc`.

This method is similar to how distribution maintainers create the payloads for package managers. See the [Arch Linux example](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/unixodbc).